# How do you increase the size of a Material UI card?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI version 4 and am incorporating cards into my website ([click here for more details](https://v4.mui.com/components/cards/)).

[image]

I want to increase the size of the entire card, so the picture appears larger. Since I just import the Material UI card "off the shelf" in my React program, I wasn't sure if it was possible to customize the sizing using CSS or some other method. Is something like this possible? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. you could style material UI components by passing in CSS class as props or you could override element style inside components by using `classes` props.

`classes={{root:classes.some-class}}`

You can see the details in API section of component. https://v4.mui.com/api/card/